# Arbitrary precision integer programming solvers?

Tags: bignum, integer-programming

Are there any free solvers capable of solving integer programming problems with large numbers (at least 336 bits)? All the solvers I've looked at appear to assume only double precision, and I haven't been able to find any that claim arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 2):

The only one that I know of is SCIP - its a really good solver and they have a beta of a version that does exact arithmetic, although I haven't tried that side of SCIP yet:
http://scip.zib.de/exactmip.shtml

Also, the people working on SCIP all seem to be really helpful, and there is an active support email list too so you are likely to get good support.

Tim